# How to receive data in DialogFlow sent from Kommunicate?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, kommunicate

I am creating a chatbot for my website. So, I am using **DialogFlow** and **Kommunicate.io** for the same. 
I added a script given by kommunicate in my html file. For sending custom data from html page to the bot, we use chatContext variable in the **"onInit"** function but I am not able to get how to use that data in my dialogflow bot. 
This is my kommunicate script :

```
(function(d, m){
        var kommunicateSettings = {"appId":"7519ee060abee2b532e8565aa0527aed","popupWidget":true,"automaticChatOpenOnNavigation":true, 
                "title": "test",
                 "appSettings": {
                        "chatWidget": {
                          "popup": true,           // To enable or disable the pre-chat popup (boolean)
                          //"emojilibrary" : true
                        },
                        "chatPopupMessage": [{
                          "message": "Wanna ask something related to "+document.title+ "?", // Message to be displayed in the pre-chat popup (string)
                          "delay": 3000                    // Delay interval of pre-chat popup (number in milliseconds)
                        }],
                 },
                 "onInit" : function(){
                     var chatContext = {
                      "lat":"Latitude° N",
                      "lon":"Longitude° E"
                    }
                    Kommunicate.updateChatContext(chatContext);
                 }
        };

        var s = document.createElement("script"); s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true;
        s.src = "https://widget.kommunicate.io/v2/kommunicate.app";
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; h.appendChild(s);
        window.kommunicate = m; m._globals = kommunicateSettings;
      })(document, window.kommunicate || {});
```

And this is my DialogFlow code :

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Payload} =require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const i18n= require('i18n');
const express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function About(agent){
    agent.add(`We are a company!`);
  }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
   intentMap.set('About the company', About);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I want to show "lat" and "lon" in my welcome message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data you pass in chatContext object from Kommunicate chat widget can be access from your fulfillment code. This data is available in request object as part of `originalDetectIntentRequest` parameter.

This is the example:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));

  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  console.log('Data passed as chatContext from Kommunicate is: ' +  JSON.stringify(request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest)  );

   .
   .
   .
   .
   .


});
```